How to choose optimal tombstone_compaction_interval?
When using Size-Tiered Compaction Strategy (STCS) for Scylla, how to decide what value of tombstone_compaction_interval to use? https://opensource.docs.scylladb.com/stable/cql/compaction.html#common-options
(it would help to have a metric for single sstable tombstone compaction)
